# Custom video streaming to web page

Tags: video-streaming, jpeg

We have a custom video camera that streams what is essentially jpeg images to our software at 12fps.  What I would like to do is display this "video" on a web page with as minimal effort as possible.

My current thinking is to write the images out and have the web page collect them, buffer up a few seconds worth then essentially swap one image for the next to create the illusion of video.  I'm not sure how well this will perform though.

Are there any better options out there? It needs to be free and fairly quick to implement!
Our core decoder software is written in C++ and we have the option of using most client side web technologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar problem an found this : http://sourceforge.net/projects/mjpg-streamer/, it should do what you are looking for.